# Scrape array of many urls in python

Tags: python

The code scrape 1 url and get all images.
How can I do if I need to scrape an array of many urls?

I try with for but i'm very new with python and now i'm learning. Thank you for every response, i i appreciate it.

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os
  
# CREATE FOLDER
def folder_create(images):
    try:
        folder_name = input("Enter Folder Name:- ")
        # folder creation
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
  
    # if folder exists with that name, ask another name
    except:
        print("Folder Exist with that name!")
        folder_create()
  
    # image downloading start
    download_images(images, folder_name)
  

# DOWNLOAD ALL IMAGES FROM THAT URL
def download_images(images, folder_name):

    # intitial count is zero
    count = 0
  
    # print total images found in URL
    print(f"Total {len(images)} Image Found!")
  
    # checking if images is not zero
    if len(images) != 0:
        for i, image in enumerate(images):
            # From image tag ,Fetch image Source URL
  
                        # 1.data-srcset
                        # 2.data-src
                        # 3.data-fallback-src
                        # 4.src
  
            # Here we will use exception handling
  
            # first we will search for "data-srcset" in img tag
            try:
                # In image tag ,searching for "data-srcset"
                image_link = image["data-srcset"]
                  
            # then we will search for "data-src" in img 
            # tag and so on..
            except:
                try:
                    # In image tag ,searching for "data-src"
                    image_link = image["data-src"]
                except:
                    try:
                        # In image tag ,searching for "data-fallback-src"
                        image_link = image["data-fallback-src"]
                    except:
                        try:
                            # In image tag ,searching for "src"
                            image_link = image["src"]

  
                        # if no Source URL found
                        except:
                            pass
  
            # After getting Image Source URL
            # We will try to get the content of image
            try:
                r = requests.get(image_link).content
                try:
  
                    # possibility of decode
                    r = str(r, 'utf-8')
  
                except UnicodeDecodeError:
  
                    # After checking above condition, Image Download start
                    filename = image_link.strip().split('/')[-1].strip()
                    print (filename)
                    #with open(f"{folder_name}/images{i+1}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
                    with open(f"{folder_name}/{filename}", "wb+") as f:
                        f.write(r)
                    # counting number of image downloaded
                    count += 1
            except:
                pass
  
        # There might be possible, that all
        # images not download
        # if all images download
        if count == len(images):
            print("All Images Downloaded!")
              
        # if all images not download
        else:
            print(f"Total {count} Images Downloaded Out of {len(images)}")
  
# MAIN FUNCTION START
def main(url):

    for val in url22:
    print(val)

    # content of URL
    r = requests.get(url)
  
    # Parse HTML Code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  
    # find all images in URL
    images = soup.findAll('img')
  
    # Call folder create function
    folder_create(images)
  
  
# take url
url = input("Enter URL:- ")

# CALL MAIN FUNCTION
main(url)
```

Comment: Please don't add lorem ipsum text to avoid the filter. It's asking you to add details, which you need to do for this question to be answerable. There any many `input()` calls here, but I can't know what values you're giving to them. Please hardcode the values or describe what I should put into these to get the program to run and reproduce the problem. What website is this? Thanks.

Comment: Its simple, The actual code scrape 1 url and get all images. I need to scrape an array of urls and get the images in folder. I have the code from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-all-images-from-a-web-page-in-python/

Comment: Maybe write a loop over the list ("array") and call your code again.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The actual code scrape 1 url and get all images. I need to scrape an array of urls and get the images in folder

So you just need to take all the `urls` as input, then call the `main()` for each `url`

```
# take comma seperated urls
urls = input("Enter URLs:- ").split(',')

for url in urls:
    main(url)
```

Comment: I have this error: main(url)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: have updated, try now

Comment: I have the same error, if you can put the urls in code and that works, its ok.

Comment: Read about indentation here :  https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp, that is basic python you should know

Comment: @Dragonasu Check the error message and the line number. Note that the code you posted in the question already has a wrong indentation (in the main function, after the `for`)